# Outlook - Domain account not resolving

Tags: microsoft-outlook, active-directory

I normally test people's Active Directory account names or email addresses by pasting them into an email (in the TO, CC, or BCC) and tabbing to the next field. Outlook will auto-resolve it to the person's name and I can verify it is accurate.

However, I ran into a situation where a user's domain account name was a sub-string of another user's domain name and Outlook would not resolve it automatically even though it should be an exact match.

Example, csmith and csmith2. Typing csmith and tabbing doesn't resolve the account.

Is there a way to make Outlook auto-resolve it?

Comment: Try Ctrl-K after enter the initial string

Comment: @RomeoNinov That is nice, but I can right click the name and do basically the same thing.

Comment: Right, but this will mean you will remove hand(s) from keyboard. And my idea is to exec the same w/o leaving keyboard :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov you should post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to accomplish address lookup in MS outlook is to type some letter/numbers and press Ctrl+k. This will autocomplete the mail (if one address is find). Or will open window where you can select from all find addresses or names (personal or distribution lists)

The same can be done via mouse, click on the letters, then click "Check names"

It is case of personal taste which way (keyboard or mouse) to use